# how to work sniper bots

Tags: spl-token, token, spl-token-program, associated-token-account, token-2022

please explain me how sniper bots work in solana. i am interested in their logic of operation.

how does it work? the bot finds a coin, but the trading pair may not appear immediately. What does the bot do at that moment, saves it in the database and then follows the appearance of this trading pair?

Comment: This question would lead to a lot of opinionated answers and the question needs a little bit more focus. Stackexchange is not for asking for full tutorials on things, but feel free to ask a more focused question